# Is it safe to combine sodium hypochlorite (bleach) sodium triphosphate (TSP) for cleaning?

Tags: safety

I've heard this combination can be particularly effective at cleaning biofilms, perhaps because the TSP is a surfacant, allowing bleach to "attack" more layers of the biofilm.

However, I'm also aware one should be cautious when mixing anything other than water with bleach, as there are a wide variety of reactions that can occur. But I've seen nothing about bleach and TSP. Should it be safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dissolved in water, trisodium phosphate $\ce{Na3PO4}$ produces ions $\ce{PO^{3-}4}$ that react by hydrolysis with water, according to $$\ce{PO^{3-}4 + H2O -> HPO^{2-}4 + OH^-}$$ So such a solution contains the ions $\ce{OH-}$, and these ions exist also in the  bleach. Indeed, bleach main ingredient is sodium hypochlorite $\ce{NaClO}$. But its solution contains significant amounts of $\ce{NaOH}$ which produce the ions $\ce{OH-}$. As both solutions (bleach and trisodium phosphate) contains the same ions, they can be mixed without any trouble. Furthermore the hypochlorite ion $\ce{ClO-}$ does not react with the phosphate ions $\ce{PO^{3-}4}$ and $\ce{HPO^{2-}4}$ .

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the more complete answer is that Na3PO4 is a [recommended stabilizer](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_better_to_prepare_chlorine_solutions_in_Phosphate_buffer_than_in_deionized_water_in_carrying_out_chlorine_disinfection_assay) for bleach.

Also, per a [ScienceDirect source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/trisodium-phosphate), to quote:

> Trisodium phosphate hydrolyzes to produce hydroxide ions. Phosphate acts as buffer...'coordinated phosphate pH control.'

where pH control prolongs the shelf life of chlorine bleach, as supported by the statement (same source):

> One down-side of chlorinated products is a limited storage stability. This instability reduces the chlorine benefit which the detergent can deliver, but also reduces the benefit of the other active ingredients which are destroyed by bleach action.

Further, more advanced radical-based bleaching is suggested by the comment:

> For dyeing with vinyl sulphone dyes, dyebath is prepared with trisodium phosphate (2%) and dye.

So, the scavenging of light (or transition metal contamination) induced radicals (which can lead to unwanted chlorate formation), is likely also an advantage of employing Na3PO4, in my opinion.